# emacs annoying key combinations

Tags: emacs, mapping, combinations, key, chord

I do not know if this bothers you too or no. Emacs for some reason uses these key combinations. Some of them are crazy. You want to undo something, guess what! ctrl+shift+dash ! 3 keys at the same time, and sometimes they are not pressed quite simultaneously and you have to repeat it. And during this long process you keep typing some unwanted characters on the screen and have to delete them latter on etc .... or ctrl+shift+< . Undo in vim is just "u" !

I am getting tired of these combinations. But I like other features of emacs and do not want to move to vim. How do you guys deal with this problem? have you mapped the keys, or got used to emacs chord keys?

Remapping emacs native keys I guess is not a good idea for various reasons. Not sure how many people actually do it.

Comment: What is it you're asking? (Is "how many people actually do it" the question?)

Comment: Generally I am asking: how do you deal with these annoying key combinations.

Comment: Remapping emacs keys is a good idea. Lots of people do it. Don't accept the defaults blindly, they are often horrible. Make emacs work like you want.

Comment: You can also use "C-/" (CTRL + slash) for undo, the same amount of keys as, say, CTRL-Z in most Windows applications. And to be fair, when you want to undo something you mistyped in vim, you need to press ESC first, to it's two key strokes as well ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I've used emacs for a very long time, and except for a very few exceptions, I just learn the keybindings.  It's mostly a matter of practice.  On Windows, you might want to consider making   CapsLock an extra Control key, which helps some of the finger gymnastics substantially.  I recommend against completely redefining the standard keybindings, but if there's something you positively just hate, of course no problem to redefine it to your liking.  Emacs reserves a few prefix keys (`C-c` for sure, and maybe some others that I can't recall right now) for user-defined key sequences.

Note also that there are sometimes alternate keybindings already defined.  With respect to undo, it is also bound to any `C-/` and `C-x u`.  I personally use the latter.  You can find this out with `C-h k C-_`.  `C-h k` is the binding for `describe-key`, which tells you what any particular key sequence you type in does, and what other keys, if any, it's on.

If you're just starting out with emacs, reading the tutorial (`C-h t`) can be somewhat useful.

Comment: God bless you! I did not know about these alternate key bindings! c-x u is now way easier for undo!

Comment: `C-x u` is positively tiresome if you need to do 50 undo's in a row. It happens that after typing some you become aware of having screwed up something mysteriously before; the best way out is to cut your new work into the paste buffer and then undo all the way back to the strange moves before.

Comment: In recent versions of emacs, you can continue undoing by repeating the `u`.  Ie,  `C-x u u u` and so on.

Comment: `C-u-5-0 C-x u`?

Comment: @robert I have no doubt that works, but in practice I never know how many steps I need to undo to get back to what I want. I usually know what my goal looks like though.

Comment: @DaleHagglund what about `C-x u` for the first one then `C-x z` and after that you only need to use `z`. It's a handy pattern to know for when you want to repeat any command. Well nearly any ...

Comment: @robert Sounds perfectly reasonable. For whatever reason, I don't use C-x z much. Like I mentioned in a comment above, I believe you can also just repeat the u at the end of C-x u

Comment: Yes was replying more for the benefit of @MarcvanLeeuwen and other onlookers ... I never knew about `C-x u` before this actually. I was always happy with `C-/` but maybe that's cause I have big hands :-( when you do repeating `u` after `C-x u` does it dispatch the undos immediately or does it stack them?

Answer (score 3):

You may define your own key combinations in a *.emacs* file. It uses lisp language, if you don't understand it, just copy/paste existing lines.

Read this page for examples: [Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_useful_user_keybinding.html)

**EDIT**
To bind undo with *Ctrl+z*:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
```

And other useful lines:

```
(global-set-key [home] 'beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key [end] 'end-of-line)
```

I like this one too, which copy/cut/paste with *Ctrl+Ins/Shift-Suppr/Shift-Ins*:

```
(pc-selection-mode)
```

Comment: This is excellent. Was what I was looking for. Any other useful lines in your .emacs that I can steal?!

Comment: I changed "line" to "file" and "buffer", but for some reason it moves to the beginning/end of the line (not file). C-z works though.

Comment: See this page to make your own: http://wttools.sourceforge.net/emacs-stuff/emacs-keybindings.html

Comment: It would be nice to add the companion of `C-z`:`C-Z` [ctrl-shift-z] as `(global-set-key (kbd "C-Z") 'redo)`

Answer (score 1):

I most certainly rebind keys. Indeed, I think many of the default keybindings are quite useless and annoying, so when I can get it, I map 'undo' to the "undo" function key, otherwise to a short combo like Ctrl-- or something. Sinsedrix has already shown how to do persistent key rebinding.

(And don't worry too much about using nonstandard bindings. True, if someone else has to type into your editor it may slightly complicate things, but that isn't really very often. It is no way comparable to defining your own keyboard layout, like Dvorak in a QWERTY environment, which is what people usually warn against.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found "Evil" which turns emacs to vim. But then there is no point in doing so. I think as you said mapping some of the keys you do not like is a better option. I am fine with double combinations, and just need to map some of these triple combination keys.

Comment: and thanks for pointing out, cause I do not know what people actually do about this. It's good to hear the experience of others.

Comment: By the way, it really really helps if you can customize your keyboard just a tiny little bit so that that left Ctrl is to the left of the A as God intended, rather than in the bottom row. Makes pressing Ctrl *way* easier on the hands.

Comment: great point. Since it's a laptop, this means I probably have to map ctrl to Capslk (I miss the right ctrl too, but that should be fine, I guess)